SonarQube - Code Coverage Issue but Unit-Test class is already implemented
I'm having an issue on SonarQube regarding code coverage.
This is the method don't covered for SonarQube:

but this is my unit-test class implemented:
package com.hitachirail.maas.acingestion.dto.utils;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import com.hitachirail.maas.acingestion.dto.PeopleCountingDataDTO;
import com.hitachirail.maas.acingestion.dto.PositionDTO;
import com.hitachirail.maas.sdk.controlleradvise.exception.ValidationException;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.NonNull;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class DTOUtilsTest {

    // region validatePositionInput

    @Test
    void test_validatePositionInput_success_validStopId_EmptyLatitude_validLongitude() {
        final PositionDTO dto =
                preparePositionDTOValidation(createPositionDto(), "stop_id", null, 45d);
        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> invokeValidatePositionInput(dto));
    }

    @Test
    void test_validatePositionInput_success_validStopId_validLatitude_EmptyLongitude() {
        final PositionDTO dto =
                preparePositionDTOValidation(createPositionDto(), "stop_id", 40d, null);
        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> invokeValidatePositionInput(dto));
    }

    @Test
    void test_validatePositionInput_success_emptyStopId_ValidLatitude_emptyLongitude() {
        final PositionDTO dto = preparePositionDTOValidation(createPositionDto(), null, 40d, null);
        assertForIngestPositionInputError(dto);
    }

    @Test
    void test_validatePositionInput_success_emptyStopId_emptyLatitude_ValidLongitude() {
        final PositionDTO dto = preparePositionDTOValidation(createPositionDto(), null, null, 15d);
        assertForIngestPositionInputError(dto);
    }

    @Test
    void test_validatePositionInput_error_emptyStopId_EmptyLatitude_EmptyLongitude() {
        final PositionDTO dto = preparePositionDTOValidation(createPositionDto(), null, null, null);
        assertForIngestPositionInputError(dto);
    }

    @NonNull private PositionDTO createPositionDto() {
        final PositionDTO dto = new PositionDTO();
        dto.setSysTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return dto;
    }

    private PositionDTO preparePositionDTOValidation(
            final PositionDTO dto,
            final String stopId,
            final Double latitude,
            final Double longitude) {
        if (dto != null) {
            dto.setStopId(stopId);
            dto.setLatitude(latitude);
            dto.setLongitude(longitude);
        }
        return dto;
    }

    private void assertForIngestPositionInputError(final PositionDTO dto) {
        if (dto != null) {
            ValidationException thrown =
                    Assertions.assertThrows(
                            ValidationException.class,
                            () -> invokeValidatePositionInput(dto));
            assertEquals(DTOUtils.INGEST_POSITION, thrown.getCode());
            assertEquals(DTOUtils.STOP_ID_OR_COUPLE_LAT_LONG_CANNOT_BE_NULL, thrown.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void invokeValidatePositionInput(final PositionDTO dto) {
        DTOUtils.validatePositionInput(List.of(dto), 7);
    }

    // endregion

    // region validatePeopleCountingDataInput

    @Test
    void validatePeopleCountingDataInput_successCase() {
        assertDoesNotThrow(
                () -> invokeValidatePeopleCountingDataInput(createPeopleCountingDataDTO()));
    }

    @Test
    void validatePeopleCountingDataInput_errorIfPeopleInIsNegative() {
        final PeopleCountingDataDTO dto = createPeopleCountingDataDTO();
        dto.setPeopleIn(-10);
        assertForIngestPeopleCountingDataError(
                dto, DTOUtils.IN_OUT_PROPERTY_CANT_BE_NEGATIVE_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Test
    void validatePeopleCountingDataInput_errorIfPeopleInIsNull() {
        final PeopleCountingDataDTO dto = createPeopleCountingDataDTO();
        dto.setPeopleIn(null);
        dto.setPeopleCount(null);
        assertForIngestPeopleCountingDataError(dto, DTOUtils.COUNT_PROPERTY_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Test
    void validatePeopleCountingDataInput_errorIfPeopleOutIsNegative() {
        final PeopleCountingDataDTO dto = createPeopleCountingDataDTO();
        dto.setPeopleOut(-10);
        assertForIngestPeopleCountingDataError(
                dto, DTOUtils.IN_OUT_PROPERTY_CANT_BE_NEGATIVE_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Test
    void validatePeopleCountingDataInput_errorIfPeopleOutIsNull() {
        final PeopleCountingDataDTO dto = createPeopleCountingDataDTO();
        dto.setPeopleOut(null);
        dto.setPeopleCount(null);
        assertForIngestPeopleCountingDataError(dto, DTOUtils.COUNT_PROPERTY_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Test
    void validatePeopleCountingDataInput_errorIfPeopleCountIsNegative() {
        final PeopleCountingDataDTO dto = createPeopleCountingDataDTO();
        dto.setPeopleCount(-10);
        assertForIngestPeopleCountingDataError(dto, "'count' property can't be negative");
    }

    @Test
    void validatePeopleCountingDataInput_errorIfPeopleCountIsNull() {
        final PeopleCountingDataDTO dto = createPeopleCountingDataDTO();
        dto.setPeopleIn(null);
        dto.setPeopleOut(null);
        dto.setPeopleCount(null);
        assertForIngestPeopleCountingDataError(dto, DTOUtils.COUNT_PROPERTY_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE);
    }

    @NonNull private PeopleCountingDataDTO createPeopleCountingDataDTO() {
        final PeopleCountingDataDTO dto = new PeopleCountingDataDTO();
        dto.setPeopleIn(10);
        dto.setPeopleOut(2);
        dto.setPeopleCount(47);
        dto.setEventTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        dto.setSysTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return dto;
    }

    private void assertForIngestPeopleCountingDataError(
            final PeopleCountingDataDTO dto, final String errorMessage) {
        if (dto != null) {
            ValidationException thrown =
                    Assertions.assertThrows(
                            ValidationException.class,
                            () -> invokeValidatePeopleCountingDataInput(dto));
            assertEquals(DTOUtils.INGEST_PEOPLE_COUNTING_DATA, thrown.getCode());
            assertEquals(errorMessage, thrown.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void invokeValidatePeopleCountingDataInput(final PeopleCountingDataDTO dto) {
        DTOUtils.validatePeopleCountingDataInput(dto, 7);
    }

    // endregion
}

As you can see, i have implemented a lot of combination for error, but error still here.
Honestly, i don't understand the problem.
Thanks a lot for the help.
I have tried to inject the DTOUtils class too, without good results.
